# Relation between integrals of powers of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

Let's assume we have a function $f: I \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. (For simplicity, we can first assume that in also only maps in $\mathbb{R}$.) We set $\langle f^k \rangle= \int_I f(x)^k dx$.

Assuming the function fulfills

$$\langle f^k \rangle=c \langle f^{k+1} \rangle, \quad c \in \mathbb{R}$$
for $k \in \{1,...,N\}$, do we know what the function $f$ is?

---

I know the constant function $f=C$ with $\langle f^k \rangle=C \cdot x^k$ fulfills the relation. But are there other functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, there is no other such function**, provided that $N$ is at least 3.

In that case we have:

$$\langle f^2\rangle=c\langle f^3\rangle\\
\langle f^3\rangle=c\langle f^4\rangle$$
or simply
$${\langle f^2\rangle\over\langle f^3\rangle}={\langle f^3\rangle\over\langle f^4\rangle}$$
or
$$\langle f^2\rangle\langle f^4\rangle=\langle f^3\rangle^2$$
But wait, that's the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) in integral form for $f$ and $f^2$:
$$\left(\int_If(x)g(x)dx\right)^2\leqslant\int_If(x)^2dx\int_Ig(x)^2dx$$
...only we want an *equality* instead, and it is known to turn into equality only when $f$ and $g$ (in our case, $f$ and $f^2$) are scalar multiples of each other. Q.e.d.

---

On a side note, $N=2$ is not enough: there are such non-constant functions that ${\langle f\rangle\over\langle f^2\rangle}={\langle f^2\rangle\over\langle f^3\rangle}$.